# How does Color Mix (Difference) node work?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, shaders, color

[image]

How does the above node setup work, and what will happen when I change the Fac value (0-1)?  What calculation is the mix node doing here when set to Difference?

Answer (score 6):

In Cycles a color is just a set of 3 numbers representing the red, blue, and green content of the color.  To perform a mathematical operation on a color Cycles splits the color up into its RGB channels, performs the operation on each channel individually, and then combines them back into a *Color* datatype again.

The *Mix RGB* node, when set to difference, returns the absolute value of the first color minus the second color.  Mathematically: `Color = |Color1 - Color2|`.

The *Fac* value controls how much this influences the output.  So if Fac is `0` the output is always `Color1`, if Fac is `1` the output is always the exact result of the mix operation chosen (in your case, Difference).  It basically just mixes `Color1` back into the result of the operation.  Mathematically: `Color = |Color1 - Color2| * Fac + Color1 * (1-Fac)`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Color = Color1 - (Fac * Color2)?