# How does the multiply color node work?

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes, mathematics

How does multiply shade node work? I've found similar [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44748/how-does-color-mix-difference-node-work), but in that case it's a "difference" parameter. What about multiply then? I've tried to look for it in Blender [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/color/mix_rgb.html), but didn't found any of formulas or good description.

Comment: multiply is described here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/color/mix_rgb.html#examples or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @lemon I mean, there is a formula for color difference - Color = |Color1 - Color2| * Fac + Color1 * (1-Fac). But how it will look for multiply color node? Should I just replace minus with multiply, or it will look different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiply simply multiplies red of one image by red of the other image, green of one image by green of other image and blue of one image by blue of the other image.

Since color components are in range $[0, 1]$, multiplication always reduces the value.

*Factor* lerps between the **A** and the result of the above multiplication. These lerping is what *Mix* mode does.

Therefore *Multiply* with a *Factor* $= x$ is the same as *Multiply* with a *Factor* $= 1$ passed to *Mix* with a *Factor* $= x$:

[image]

The purpose of Distance → Compare is to show both upper Multiply, and lower Multiply + Mix are equivalent (same color result).

## Math Formula

The Multiply with *Factor* $ = 1$ is simply $A × B$.

The Mix (lerping) is $(1-f)A + fB$, or as Marty Fouts puts it (link below), it's $A$ plus the difference between $A$ and $B$ multiplied by *Factor*: $A+f(B−A)$.

Therefore Multiply with *Factor* is: $$(1-f)A + fAB$$ or $$A + f(AB - A)$$.

More reading:

[What does the MixRGB or Mix Shader node factor do exactly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/253944/60486)

Comment: So, the formula for multiply color "Color = |Color1 * Color2| * Fac + Color1 * (1-Fac)" is not correct? I just can't figure out the math part of it.

Comment: @Сергей see edit.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you!