# Is multiplying the color input same as multiplying the strength of Background/Emission shaders? Like in the screenshot

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

Is multiplying the color input same as multiplying the strength of Background/Emission shaders? Like in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the multiply color node work?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/309677/how-does-the-multiply-color-node-work)

Comment: I think the availability of the clamp is the only difference

Comment: As long as you leave the _Factor_ at 1 and the _Clamp Result_ disabled the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Pretty much. You will get the same result.